# Is there anyway I can prevent a push notification from displaying on the client side?

Tags: java, android, urbanairship.com

I'm using UrbanAirship for push notifications. Everything is working fine, but there are certain scenarios where I wouldn't like to display the push notification coming from urban. Do I have to handle this on the server side or can I handle it on the client side?

If possible, how would I handle this on the client side? I've tried canceling the notification, and that works, but it still displays the rollover message in the status bar.

Comment: _PushNotificationBuilder_ seems an interface you might want to take a look at. If you see a push message, you do not want to show notification for, in its _buildNotification_ method you can return null ; http://docs.urbanairship.com/reference/libraries/android/latest/reference/com/urbanairship/push/PushNotificationBuilder.html  --  I have absolutely no experience with UrbanAirship though just took a look on their API docs

Comment: Are you writing native Android code, or using something like phonegap?

Comment: @harism, thanks, it looks like that will help. I am looking at it now.

Comment: @CarlAnderson, yessir, I am writing native android code. I've udated the tags.

Comment: Is UrbanAirship on the client side, or server side?
My app uses a BroadcastReceiver subclass to actually create the Notification that goes onto the tray, but it's not clear whether you have a similar setup or not.

Comment: @CarlAnderson, I have the same setup. I have extended `BroadcastReceiver` and overridden `onReceive`, but that method only allows you to perform actions after the notification has been displayed, not actually block it from displaying.

Comment: and Urban is on both the client and the server side... isn't that the only way for urban to work? o.o

Comment: @harism, your comment led to me getting it. If you'd like to add an answer, I'll accept it. Otherwise I will submit the answer and my implementation myself.

Comment: tambykojak, I have no experience with UrbanAirship, had never heard of it before. My app is all native code, and my broadcast receiver either creates a Notification, or nothing gets put in the tray. I get access to the data before a notification is created, so your question didn't quite make sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

You need to override Airship's notification factory for this:

```
package your.package;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;

import com.urbanairship.push.PushMessage;
import com.urbanairship.push.notifications.DefaultNotificationFactory;

public class PushNotificationFactory extends DefaultNotificationFactory {

    public PushNotificationFactory(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public Notification createNotification(@NonNull PushMessage message, int notificationId) {
        boolean shouldWeShowNotification = false; // your condition goes here
        if (shouldWeShowNotification) {
            return super.createNotification(message, notificationId);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

and when taking off:

```
UAirship.takeOff(this, new UAirship.OnReadyCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onAirshipReady(UAirship airship) {
        NotificationFactory notificationFactory = new PushNotificationFactory(getApplicationContext());
        airship.getPushManager().setNotificationFactory(notificationFactory);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `BroadcastReceiver` in your app to intercept the push. You can then choose to display a custom notification or not.

Check out the setup docs http://docs.urbanairship.com/build/android_features.html#set-up

Comment: That's what I originally thought, but I discovered that this only allows you to execute some block of code on the RECEIVED, REGISTERED, or OPENED actions. Not prevent it from opening. Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: I've solved this on a work project but can't check the code until tomorrow. I create a custom notification once my `BroadcastReceiver` matches a `PushManager.ACTION_PUSH_RECEIVED` action. If I don't run the custom notification code from here then I don't see a notification. Will update tomorrow if still unsolved.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Kotlin:

```
class PushNotificationFactory(context: Context) : NotificationFactory(context) {

    override fun createNotification(message: PushMessage, notificationId: Int): Notification? {
        val notificationWillBeShowed = false // your condition goes here
        return if (notificationWillBeShowed) {
            // Show notification
            super.createNotification(message, notificationId)
        } else {
            // Prevent notification from showing
            null
        }
    }
}


class UrbanAirshipAutopilot : Autopilot()  {

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    override fun onAirshipReady(airship: UAirship) {
        airship.pushManager.userNotificationsEnabled = true
        val context = UAirship.getApplicationContext()
        val notificationFactory = PushNotificationFactory(context)
        airship.pushManager.notificationFactory = notificationFactory
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
            val notificationManager = context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            val defaultChannelId = context.getString(R.string.notification_channel_id_default)
            val defaultChannelName = context.getString(R.string.notification_channel_name_default)
            val channel = NotificationChannel(defaultChannelId, defaultChannelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }
    }

    override fun createAirshipConfigOptions(context: Context): AirshipConfigOptions? {
        val defaultChannelId = context.getString(R.string.notification_channel_id_default)
        return AirshipConfigOptions.Builder()
                .setDevelopmentAppKey(BuildConfig.URBAN_AIRSHIP_APP_KEY_DEVELOPMENT)
                .setDevelopmentAppSecret(BuildConfig.URBAN_AIRSHIP_APP_SECRET_DEVELOPMENT)
                .setProductionAppKey(BuildConfig.URBAN_AIRSHIP_APP_KEY_PRODUCTION)
                .setProductionAppSecret(BuildConfig.URBAN_AIRSHIP_APP_SECRET_PRODUCTION)
                .setInProduction(!BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                .setGcmSender(BuildConfig.CLOUD_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID)     // FCM/GCM sender ID
//                .setNotificationIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
//                .setNotificationAccentColor(ContextCompat(getContext(), R.color.accent))
                .setNotificationChannel(defaultChannelId)
                .build()
    }
}
```